# Accessing a Time Capsule manually via terminal using iCloud credentials

Tags: macos, ssh, script, sync, icloud

I'm assuming that the task noted above should be possible, as the task doesn't seem like it should be far different from accessing a Mac computer via SSH or through Go -> Connect to Server on OSX. The standard way to do this with a Mac computer through iCloud credentials would be the following: http://subrosasoft.com/blog/guide/remote-ssh-into-your-mac-through-icloud using the format: username@computer-name.[account number].members.btmm.icloud.com. My problem seems to be that I have no idea what I should use for username@computer-name. I've already tried the device name, and there isn't really a user name. There are two distinguished parts for the device, the HDD portion and the device portion. Has anyone been able to do this? Particularly, I would like to run some syncing scripts of mine for stuff off of my LAN. When writing the script, my credentials for the remote in are local rather set to map the drive remotely.

Comment: I think this would be helpful

[http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-can-i-access-my-time-capsule-remotely][1]


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-can-i-access-my-time-capsule-remotely